# Checkbox doesn't work on first click when checked by default

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have some checkboxes that doesn't work in first click when they are already checked by default.

What's happen is: When I click in te checked checkbox he fire `Page_Load` but doesn't fire `OnCheckedChanged` event and keep checked until I click again(after this all checkboxes start to work normally).

In the tests I made, I notice that if I keep the Panel witch include the checkboxes always visible this problem does not occur and if I remove the `OnCheckedChanged` event too

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updApply">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlApply">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlAplicaDescontoEstabelecimento">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxApply" runat="server" 
                                                onchange="loadUI();" 
                                                OnCheckedChanged="apply_CheckedChanged" 
                                                AutoPostBack="True" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                                    
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I think it's important to say that in the code behind there are some functions that control whether the Panel is visible

Thanks!

Comment: What is OnChange doing? It is not in the MSDN for asp:checkbox. Is it a property in your code behind? When clicking the checkbox the first time, do you get a console error? I suspect you have some other issues here. Is your updatepanel wrapped inside another updatepanel?

Comment: OnChange opens a load on the screen, I've tried without it and the same thing happens.
Console do not show me any error when I click for the first time. And the UpdatePanel isn't wrapped inside another updatepanel. @ClearlyClueless

Comment: Instead of using visible, try setting the css style display:none. Visible removes the control fronlm the pages markup entirely during render and may remove it's persisted value from viewstate resulting in the event not recognizing the changed value. Explicitly setting the default checked value may help as well

Comment: @ClearlyClueless Thank you!!!! This solution worked. I will update the post with the solution

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! Whenever you find a solution to solve your problem in a comment, write an answer to your question and mark it as the answer so that it can be better referenced by future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using visible, try setting the css style `display:none`. Visible removes the control fronlm the pages markup entirely during render and may remove it's persisted value from viewstate resulting in the event not recognizing the changed value.

Another possible solution would be explicitly setting the default checked value to guarantee it makes it into viewstate, though it checked should default to false per the MSD.